# using min and max date in jQuery-UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to limit what the users can select from the date-picker so i only need to let the user select the last 2 days.  I also don't want them to select today's date and forward.  how can i limit the selection for the date-picker only for the last 2 days and nothing else?  thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -2 });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -2, maxDate: -1 });
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/tisidi/1/edit?html,js,output)